# Why is PowerShell applying the predicate of a `Where` to an empty list

Tags: arrays, powershell, enumeration, powershell-core, convertfrom-json

If I run this in PowerShell, I expect to see the output `0` (zero):

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

$x = "[]" | ConvertFrom-Json | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
Write-Host $x.Count
```

Instead, I get this error:

```
The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the     property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:44
+     $x = "[]" | ConvertFrom-Json | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

If I put braces around `"[]" | ConvertFrom-Json` it becomes this:

```
$y = ("[]" | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
Write-Host $y.Count
```

And then it "works".

**What is wrong before introducing the parentheses?**

To explain the quotes around "works" - setting strict mode `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` indicates that I call `.Count` on a `$null` object. That is solved by wrapping in `@()`:

```
$z = @(("[]" | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" })
Write-Host $z.Count
```

I find this quite dissatisfying, but it's an aside to the actual question.

Comment: First of all, `=` is not `-eq`! The second variation "works" because the `Where` is never evaluated (the collection is empty). Replace `"[]"` with `"[{}]"` for more insight. As to why the same doesn't apply to the first variation (i.e. why there is a pipeline, and the `Where` is applied to it) -- that's more interesting, and probably has to do with the subtleties of `ConvertFrom-Json`...

Comment: Voting to close as typo.  The problem is with the `=`, nothing else.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Typo fixed. Also pulled over setting strict mode, something I'd omitted. The problem persists.

Comment: Strict mode causes an exception to be thrown if you try accessing a property that doesn't exist.  If you want to avoid this, you should be using one of the other parameter sets such as: `| ? Name -eq Baz`

Comment: To clear up potential confusion over what this question is about: The question is why JSON input that becomes an _empty array_ in PowerShell via `ConvertFrom-Json` surprisingly still sends an object through the pipeline and executes the `Where-Object` script block, whereas it doesn't do that if you use an empty array directly (`@() | Where ...`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is PowerShell applying the predicate of a `Where` to an empty list?

Because `ConvertFrom-Json` tells `Where-Object` to not attempt to enumerate its output.

Therefore, PowerShell attempts to access the `name` property on the empty array itself, much like if we were to do:

```
$emptyArray = New-Object object[] 0
$emptyArray.name
```

When you enclose `ConvertFrom-Json` in parentheses, powershell interprets it as a *separate* pipeline that executes and ends *before* any output can be sent to `Where-Object`, and `Where-Object` can therefore not know that `ConvertFrom-Json` wanted it to treat the array as such.

---

We can recreate this behavior in powershell by explicitly calling `Write-Output` with the `-NoEnumerate` switch parameter set:

```
# create a function that outputs an empty array with -NoEnumerate
function Convert-Stuff 
{
  Write-Output @() -NoEnumerate
}

# Invoke with `Where-Object` as the downstream cmdlet in its pipeline
Convert-Stuff | Where-Object {
  # this fails
  $_.nonexistingproperty = 'fail'
}

# Invoke in separate pipeline, pass result to `Where-Object` subsequently
$stuff = Convert-Stuff
$stuff | Where-Object { 
  # nothing happens
  $_.nonexistingproperty = 'meh'
}
```

`Write-Output -NoEnumerate` internally calls `Cmdlet.WriteObject(arg, false)`, which in turn causes the runtime to *not* enumerate the `arg` value during parameter binding against the downstream cmdlet (in your case `Where-Object`)

---

> Why would this be desireable?

In the specific context of parsing JSON, this behavior might indeed be desirable:

```
$data = '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]' |ConvertFrom-Json
```

Should I not expect exactly 5 objects from `ConvertFrom-Json` now that I passed 5 valid JSON documents to it? :-)

Comment: Interesting! How does `ConvertFrom-Json` "tell" `Where-Object` not to attempt to enumerate it's output?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! Why would this be desireable? Disallowing it seems to break pipelines, but I assume there's a good reason for why we _wouldn't_ want something to enumerate later in the pipeline?

Comment: ...I suppose if I wanted to pipe a resulting json-decoded object in to something else it'd be a pain if it were decomposed in to multiple objects when it just happens to be an array. That'd result in multiple calls to the next stage of the pipeline where normally we'd expect one. Ok, thanks again Mathias, shout if I'm mis-thinking :)

Comment: The surprising "un-PowerShell-like" default behavior of `ConvertFrom-Json` is discussed in https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424, along with potentially introduce a switch such as `-[No]Enumerate` to offer control over the enumeration behavior.

Comment: Quibble: `Where-Object` never has any knowledge of how the preceding pipeline segment produced its output - it simply operates on the inputs as provided: a single object that happens to be an array with a direct `ConvertFrom-Json` call, and the forced enumeration of that array when enclosed in `(...)`.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah, that's why I clarified that it "causes the **runtime** to *not* enumerate [...] during parameter binding against the downstream cmdlet" - but for the initial TLDR/ELI5 answer, I think it's a fair interpretation to say that "Where-Object doesn't know" :)

Comment: But there's still the phrase _Because ConvertFrom-Json tells Where-Object to not attempt to enumerate its output_ at the top, which is misleading, because the former doesn't tell the latter anything. If anything, the former tells the _pipeline_ not to enumerate.

Comment: I agree completely, a more technically correct phrase would be *Because ConvertFrom-Json tells the runtime to not attempt to enumerate its output before deciding how to bind it to the input parameters exposed by Where-Object* and an even more correct version would be "When you hit enter, a signal is sent to the hardware scanner bus to which your keyboard is connected which in turn cause [436802 words later ...] and `consolhostv2.dll` finally calls the GFX renderer..." - I maintain that my _simplification_ is appropriate at the layer of abstraction we're discussion :)

Comment: Ignoring the unwarranted sarcasm: To me, it's not a simplification, it's a false abstraction that actively suggests a relationship that doesn't exist, as evidenced by @ledneb inquiring about it.

Answer (score 2):

With an **empty array as direct pipeline input, *nothing* is sent through the pipeline**, because the **array is *enumerated***, and since there's nothing to enumerate - because an empty array has no elements - the `Where` (`Where-Object`) script block is never executed:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

# The empty array is enumerated, and since there's nothing to enumerate,
# the Where[-Object] script block is never invoked.
@() | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
```

By contrast, **in PowerShell versions up to v6.x** `"[]" | ConvertFrom-Json` produces an empty array *as a single output object* rather than having its (nonexistent) elements enumerated, because **`ConvertFrom-Json` in these versions *doesn't* enumerate the elements of arrays it outputs**; it is the equivalent of:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

# Empty array is sent as a single object through the pipeline.
# The Where script block is invoked once and sees $_ as that empty array.
# Since strict mode is in effect and arrays have no .name property
# an error occurs.
Write-Output -NoEnumerate @() | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
```

**`ConvertFrom-Json`'s behavior is *surprising* in the context of PowerShell** - cmdlets generally *enumerate* multiple outputs - but **is defensible in the context of JSON parsing**; after all, information would be *lost* if `ConvertFrom-Json` enumerated the empty array, given that you wouldn't then be able to distinguish that from *empty JSON input* (`"" | ConvertFrom-Json`).

The consensus was that *both* use cases are legitimate and that users should have a *choice* between the two behaviors - enumeration or not - by way of a *switch* (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424) for the associated discussion).

Therefore, **starting with PowerShell [Core] 7.0**:

- **Enumeration *is* now performed by default.**
- An opt-in to the *old* behavior is available via the new **`-NoEnumerate`** switch.

In **PowerShell 6.x-**, **if enumeration is desired, the - obscure - workaround is to *force enumeration* by simply enclosing the `ConvertFrom-Json` call in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) (which converts it to an *expression*, and expressions always enumerate a command's output when used in the pipeline):

```
# (...) around the ConvertFrom-Json call forces enumeration of its output.
# The empty array has nothing to enumerate, so the Where script block is never invoked.
("[]" | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
```

---

As for **what you tried**: your attempt to access the `.Count` property and your use of `@(...)`:

```
$y = ("[]" | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where { $_.name -eq "Baz" }
$y.Count # Fails with Set-StrictMode -Version 2 or higher
```

With the `ConvertFrom-Json` call wrapped in `(...)`, your overall command returns "nothing": loosely speaking, `$null`, but, more accurately, an "array-valued null", which is the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton that indicates the absence of output from a command. (In most contexts, the latter is treated the same as `$null`, though notably not when used as pipeline input.)

`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` doesn't have a `.Count` property, which is why with `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher in effect, you'll get a `The property 'count' cannot be found on this object.` error.

By wrapping the entire pipeline in `@(...)`, the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), you ensure treatment of the output as an *array*, which, with array-valued null output, creates an empty array - which *does* have a `.Count` property.

Note that **you *should* be able to call `.Count` on `$null` and `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`**, given that PowerShell adds a `.Count` property to *every* object, if not already present - including to scalars, in a commendable effort to unify the handling of collections and scalars.

That is, with `Set-StrictMode` set to `-Off` (the default) or to `-Version 1` the following *does* work and - sensibly - returns `0`:

```
# With Set-StrictMode set to -Off (the default) or -Version 1:

# $null sensibly has a count of 0.
PS> $null.Count
0

# So does the "array-valued null", [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value 
# `. {}` is a simple way to produce it.
PS> (. {}).Count # `. {}` outputs 
0
```

**That the above currently *doesn't* work with `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher (as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0), should be considered a *bug***, as reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798) (by Jeffrey Snover, no less).