# Convert to csv from json in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv, scripting

this is my csv:

```
"name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json
```

Gives me:

```
[
{
    "name":  "Play",
    "data":  "http://{gho}.domain.com/"
},
{
    "name":  "BDomain",
    "data":  "domain.com"
},
{
    "name":  "Charts",
    "data":  "2"
},
{
    "name":  "Compress",
    "data":  "0"
},
{
    "name":  "CompressJ",
    "data":  "0"
}
]
```

I would now like to get that csv back from my json, however the chains of | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-CSV are not working, and I am curious why not?

Comment: this is a duplicate refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594860/convert-json-to-csv-using-powershell

Comment: the file in that question doesnt exist so i was uncertain of the format, but will look into it, thank you

Comment: well, when trying to get the 'results' property ps throws that results cannot be found, if doing just standard |convertfrom-json | convertto-csv it returns some metadata formatted as csv

Comment: @tawfikboujeh, the issue here is the pre-v7 non-enumerating behavior of `ConvertFrom-Json`, which is - incidentally -  _bypassed_ in the solution to the linked question, where accessing a _property_ implicitly causes enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [Steven's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014393/45375) with a succinct summary and a cross-edition perspective:

- In **PowerShell [Core] v7+**, no extra effort is needed: appending `| ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Csv` to your code works as-is.
- In **Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core] v6.x**, you need to *force enumeration* of `ConvertFrom-Json`'s output in order for `ConvertTo-Csv` to work correctly, because, against PowerShell's usual behavior, `ConvertFrom-Json` outputs a JSON array *as a whole, as a single object* to the pipeline.

  - It is the fact that this behavior is *unusual* that prompted the v7+ change - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578551/45375) for background information.
  - The simplest way to force enumeration - i.e. to send an output-as-a-whole array's / collection's elements *one by one* to the pipeline is to use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).

```
# Works in all PowerShell versions, but in v7+ the (...) is no longer necessary.
(
"name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json |
  ConvertFrom-Json
) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This yields:

```
"name","data"
"Play","http://{gho}.domain.com/"
"BDomain","domain.com"
"Charts","2"
"Compress","0"
"CompressJ","0"
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of `ConvertFrom-Json` is single array being passed down the pipeline as such. This is a consequence of how `ConvertFrom-Json` is writing it's output.  It's probably collecting everything and outputting the array in one `Write-Output` command (implicit or otherwise) instead of streaming each object down the pipeline as they are created.  It's probably a consequence of how the cmdlet is written and may have been necessary.

Your current code is likely generating a csv like:

```
"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"5","5","5","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"
```

These are the properties of the array not the objects in it.  One way to get around it just park the data in a variable:

```
$Json = "name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0" | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
ConvertTo-Json

# Now you can convert back to csv without issue:
$Json = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Json | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

> Note: if you send $Json directly like `$Json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Csv...` you may have the same issue.

Iterating over the Json objects also seems to work:

```
$Json = "name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0" | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
ConvertTo-Json

$Json | 
ConvertFrom-Json |
ForEach-Object{ $_ } | 
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks to @notjustme , you can shorten this using `(...)` like:

```
($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Csv
```

> Note: Corrected per [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055115/4749264).

All of these options are essentially placing the array in-front of the pipe to bypass the internal behavior of `ConvertFrom-Json`

Again not 100% sure why ConvertFrom-Json behaves this way. I'll update with additional information when I find a more formal explanation.

Comment: `$($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Csv` should work though.

Comment: @notjustme I didn't think of it but yes it should work.

Comment: +1; re _why_: please see my answer. As for `$(...)`: `(...)` will do, and is generally preferable - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).

Comment: Thanks as always. Regrettably I didn't check 7+ in this case.  I agree I rarely use `$(...)` outside of expanding strings. I missed it as I was copying from @notjustme's comment.

Comment: Oh yeah, muscle memory... Sooo many strings expanded on a daily basis. :)