# How can we handle json null value in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, api

I created powershell script which request API and get response but many times I getting null value without double quotes in JSON object which created error in other script.

How can I put double quotes where getting null value.

Response :

```
{ "Name" : { 
             "Tag1" : "server1",
             "Tag2" : null,
             "Tag3" : "web"
            }
}
```

Here, I expecting "Tag2" : "null" ( need double quotes where get null response)

Context :
I'm fetching tag from azure vm, if that particular tag is not available then itz return null as expected.

```
Ex.
 $webvmdata = @{
 Vmtype = $wenvm.Tags.vmtype
  }
  $webvmdata | ConvertTo-Json
```

How can we easily handle this using powershell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use other other people's avatars. Especially not this one.

Comment: *"expecting "Tag2" : "null" (need double quotes where get null response)"* - No, you don't. This case is already easily handled in PowerShell by default. You're doing something wrong. Show more context.

Comment: @Tomalak i added powershell code

Comment: So you really want `null` - which translates into `$null` when parsed in PowerShell objects with `ConvertFrom-Json` (which is built into `Invoke-RestMethod`) - to be replaced with the _string_ `"null"`?

Comment: @mklement0 First, Without Double quotes null value which getting errors in python which loading. Getting "malformed string" error. So I need double quotes null value. Even used ConvertFrom-Json where also getting without double quotes for null.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- Generally speaking, `null` is a legitimate JSON value that becomes `$null` when PowerShell parses JSON into custom objects with its [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet, which, in effect, is also built into [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod).

If you really need to transform the `null` values into `"null"` values - i.e. *strings* - in your JSON, the most robust - but not fast - approach is to:

- Let `ConvertFrom-Json` parse your JSON into custom objects...
- ... then walk the internal structure of these objects to look for `$null` property values and replace them with string `'null'`...

  - See the **bottom section** for **generalized helper function `Edit-LeafProperty`** that encapsulates this behavior.
- ... and convert the modified objects back to JSON.

```sh
# Parse JSON into custom object(s).
$fromJson = ConvertFrom-Json @'
{
  "Name": {
    "Tag1": "server1",
    "Tag2": null,
    "Tag3": "web"
  }
}
'@

# Transform the object(s) in place.
$fromJson | ForEach-Object {
  # Helper script block that walks the object graph
  $sb = {
    foreach ($el in @($args[0])) {
      if ($el -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]) { # Nested array
        foreach ($subEl in $el) { & $sb $subEl } # Recurse
      }
      elseif ($el -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
        foreach ($prop in $el.psobject.Properties) { 
          # If the property value is $null, replace it with string 'null'
          if ($null -eq $prop.Value) { $prop.Value = 'null' }
          elseif ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
            & $sb $prop.Value  # Recurse
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
  # Call the helper script block with the input object.
  & $sb $_
} 

# Convert the transformed object(s) back to JSON
ConvertTo-Json $fromJson
```

Output (note the `"null"`):

```json
{
  "Name": {
    "Tag1": "server1",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "web"
  }
}
```

**Caveat** re **single-element arrays**:

If your input JSON is an array (`[ ... ]`) that happens to contain just *one* element, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you need to add `-NoEnumerate` to the `ConvertFrom-Json` call in order to parse the JSON into a PowerShell array - otherwise, you'll get just get that one element itself, not wrapped in an array. (This isn't necessary in *Windows PowerShell*).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

#### With generalized helper function `Edit-LeafProperty`:

If you define the helper function below (*before* running the following code), the code simplifies to the following:

```sh
@'
{
  "Name": {
    "Tag1": "server1",
    "Tag2": null,
    "Tag3": "web"
  }
}
'@  | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Edit-LeafProperty -PassThru { if ($null -eq $_.Value) { $_.Value = 'null' } } |
    ConvertTo-Json
```

Note:

- Each leaf property (an object property that doesn't itself contain another, nested `[pscustomobject]`) is passed to the specified script block (`{ ... }`) bound to `$_`, where its `.Value` (and, if needed, `.Name`) property can be examined and updated, as needed.
- `-PassThru` passes each modified object through (outputs it after modification), so that the result can directly be piped to `ConvertTo-Json`

  - The usual caveat re potentially unexpected truncation of the output applies: use 
    `-Depth` as needed for object graphs more than 2 levels deep - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375)
- The caveats re array preservation in PowerShell (Core) apply as before, with an additional twist:

  - Use `ConvertFromJson -NoEnumerate` to preserve (potentially nested) single-element arrays as such.
  - Because of the use of an intermediate streaming command - `Edit-LeafProperty` - use `ConvertTo-Json -AsArray` if you need to guarantee that the output JSON is an array, even when containing just one element.

Note that the function is designed to work with `[pscustomobject]` ([`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`]) graphs only, such as returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

**`Edit-LeafProperty` source code**:

```sh
function Edit-LeafProperty {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [AllowNull()]
    $InputObject,
    [switch] $PassThru
  )
  begin {
    # Helper script block that walks the object graph
    $sb = {
      foreach ($el in @($args[0])) {
        if ($el -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]) { # Nested array
          foreach ($subEl in $el) { & $sb $subEl } # Recurse
        }
        elseif ($el -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
          foreach ($prop in $el.psobject.Properties) { 
            if ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
              & $sb $prop.Value # Recurse
            }
            else {
              # Invoke the leaf-property processing script block with
              # the property at hand bound to $_
              ForEach-Object $ScriptBlock -InputObject $prop
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }

  process {
    & $sb $InputObject # Walk the input object at hand.
    if ($PassThru) { $InputObject } # Pass it through, if requested.
  }

}
```

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578551/45375) for what prompted this change in behavior.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I can use it..but we can do it quick way by using powershell function or something else ?

Comment: @Nullpointer, there is no built-in function, but you can wrap the object-graph walker functionality in a custom function. Please see my update, which defines and uses generalized helper function `Edit-LeafProperty`.