# How to Stop powershell form Converting the variable assigment of a boolean to Uppercase letter

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I am trying to format a json and do dynamic variable assignment but once the boolean value is assigned powershell is changing the casetype for the first letter to uppercase.
I still want to maintain the case type for my input values both lowercase and uppercase as it is in my json file.

Any help?

```
      {

          "input": true,
          "variable": "Relative path",
       }

  $path= "L:\test\parameter.json"
  $json = Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json
  foreach ($data in $json.PSObject.Properties) { New-Variable -name $($data.name) -value $($data.value) -Force}
  
  echo $input
  True   ->>> I want it to be "true" and the value of variable to still be "Relative Path"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you mustn't use `$input` as a custom variable, because it is an [*automatic* variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) managed by PowerShell.

Leaving that aside, [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) converts a `true` JSON value - a Boolean - into the equivalent [.NET Boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Boolean) (`System.Boolean`, represented as `[bool]` in PowerShell). The representation of this value in PowerShell is `$true`.

Printing this value to the console (host) effectively calls its `.ToString()` method in order to obtain a *string* representation, and that string representation happens to start with an *uppercase* letter:

```sh
PS> $true
True
```

**If you need an all-lowercase representation, call `.ToString().ToLower()`**, or, for brevity, use an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) and call `.ToLower()` on it:

```sh
PS> "$true".ToLower() # In this case, the same as $true.ToString().ToLower()
true
```

---

If you want to **apply the all-lowercase representation *automatically* to all Booleans**, you have two options:

- **Modify *the data***, by replacing the Boolean values with their desired string representations:

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591008/45375) shows how to walk a `[pscustomobject]` object graph returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` and update its (leaf) properties.
- **Preferably, only modify the *display formatting*** of `[bool]` values, without needing to modify the data, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests.

  - See below.

---

**(Temporarily) overriding the `.ToString()` method of type `[bool]`:**

[`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata) can be used to override the members of arbitrary .NET types, but there is a **limitation due to a *bug*** - reported in [GitHub issue #14561](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14561) - present up to at least PowerShell 7.2.2:

- A `.ToString()` override is *not* honored when you *cast* an instance to `[string]` (e.g., `[string] $true`) or when you use it in an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (e.g, `"$true"`)

However, with *implicit* stringification of Booleans, as happens during for-display formatting, it does work:

```sh
# Override the .ToString() method of [bool] (System.Boolean) instances:
# Save preexisting type data, if any.
$prevTypeData = Get-TypeData -TypeName System.Boolean
# Add a ScriptMethod member named 'ToString' that outputs an
# all-lowercase representation of the instance at hand. ('true' or 'false')
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Boolean `
                -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName ToString `
                -Value { if ($this) { 'true' } else { 'false' } } `
                -Force

# Output a sample custom object with two Boolean properties.
[pscustomobject] @{ 
  TrueValue = $true
  FalseValue = $false
}

# Restore the original behavior:
# Note: In production code, it's best to put this in the `finally`
#       block of try / catch / finally statement.
# Remove the override again...
Remove-TypeData -TypeName System.Boolean
# ... and restore the previous data, if any.
if ($prevTypeData) { Update-TypeData -TypeData $prevTypeData }
```

Note: You cannot *scope* `Update-TypeData` calls, which invariably take effect *session-globally*, so it's best to remove the override again with [`Remove-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-typedata) and restore any preexisting type data, if any, as shown above.

- zett42 has generalized the approach above to create a general-purpose 
  `Invoke-WithTemporaryTypeData` function that scopes type-data modifications to a given piece of code (script block): see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/zett42/0cbb80fe12a416123a7652a9ae3b17b9).

Output (note the all-lowercase property values):

```sh
TrueValue FalseValue
--------- ----------
     true      false
```