# Is there a way to tell if a PSObject has children?

Tags: powershell, psobject

I am working to build a way to iterate through all the key value pairs of a PSObject that was created by using `ConvertFrom-Json`.

To do this, I need a way to know if a given PSObject has one or more children.

So, given the following JSON:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I run this code:

```
$settings = Get-Content -Raw $pathToFile | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($base in $settings.PSObject.Properties) 
{
    if ($base.HasChildren -eq $true)
    {
        // Iterate Deeper
    }
}
```

When I am on the "Logging" node, `$base` has true for `HasChildren` but `AllowedHosts` has false.

Obviously, there is no such method of `HasChildren`, so this would not work.  But I am wondering if there is a a way to find this out?

Comment: you can check if `$base.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` // is this just for coding exercise or are you looking to traverse a json programmatically ? Note that this has been answered before

Comment: Hmm, another take aside from Santiagos is perhaps parsing the raw text: `$settings = ($rawJson = Get-Content -Raw $pathToFile) | ConvertFrom-Json`. Then you could convert it to a char array counting the openings: `$rawJson.ToCharArray().Where{$_ -match '\[|{'}.Count`.

Comment: In addition to @mklement0 correct answer, you might also consider the [`-AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json#-ashashtable) parameter (introduced in PowerShell 6.0): `(ConvertFrom-Json $Json -AsHashTable).Values |Where-Object { $_ -is [HashTable] }`  or (considering your background), fall back on the [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq nemespace](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/n_newtonsoft_json_linq.htm) to iterate through the objects, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352656/1701026

Answer (score 1):

What [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) outputs is a `[pscustomobject]` graph, so you can indeed test properties of that graph enumerated via the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) for being instances of that type using `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests:

```bash
foreach ($base in $settings.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($base.Value -is [pscustomobject]) {
        # Iterate Deeper
    }
}
```

Note:

- `[pscustomobject]` works reliably with `ConvertFrom-Json`, but - for obscure technical reasons - the generally more robust solution is to use the (technically incorrect) [`[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject). Surprisingly, `[pscustomobject]` is the same as `[psobject]`, whose full type name is *different*, namely [`System.Management.Automation.PSObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject). See [GitHub issue #11921](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11921) for background information.
- There are many answers on this site that show how to recursively walk a `[pscustomobject]` graph, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591008/45375).