# Powershell parsing API ouput JSON

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a way to manipulate the output obtained from the API request.

The output is similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "19/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0001",
        "ProductName": "Fizzy Drink",
        "Cost": "2.32",
        "Currency": "USD",
    },
    {
        "Date": "16/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0002",
        "ProductName": "Dark Chocolate",
        "Cost": "6.52",
        "Currency": "USD",
    },
    {
        "Date": "10/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0003",
        "ProductName": "Snacks",
        "Cost": "4.2",
        "Currency": "USD",
    }
]
```

How can manipulate this type of data?

My goal is to obtain something like this:

> - Date 19/5/2022
> - ProductID 0001
> - ProductName Fizzy Drink
> - Cost 2.32
> - Currency USD

> - Date 16/5/2022
> - ProductID 0002
> - ProductName Dark Chocolate
> - Cost 6.52
> - Currency USD

I've tried something like this: (without success)

```
foreach($GetInfo in $IDInfo)  
{  
$ID = $GetInfo.data.Date 
$Name = $GetInfo.data.ProductId 
Write-Host $ID  
Write-Host $Name  
}
```

But every time I got, the date on one line, ProductID on the second line, and ProductName on the third line.

like:

```
19/5/2022 16/5/2022 16/5/2022 
0001 0002 0003 
Fizzy Drink Dark Chocolate Snacks
```

Comment: Can we see your own attempts at this? You may be after `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: Your output doesn’t appear to be valid json (or “json lines”) for a number of reasons. Can you please post a sample output that is *exactly* like your output rather than just “similar”? Anonymise it if needed, but it should be syntactically identical otherwise answers are going to focus on your invalid format…

Comment: If you copy the JSON now in the question, open a command prompt, and enter `Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Json`, this appears to produce exactly what you need. what more would you expect?

Comment: Despite my test I'm unable to get a correct result :( 
I can retrieve data, but every time data are: date date date instead of: Date productID | date ProductID

Answer (score 0):

Your output implies that `$GetInfo.data` is an *array*, which means that a property access such as `.Date` uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), which means that the `.Date` values *of all array elements* are returned.

Thus, you need an *inner* loop as well:

```bash
foreach($GetInfo in $IDInfo)  
{  
  # Loop over the elements of the array in .data
  foreach ($element in $GetInfo.data) { 
     $Id = $element.Date
     $Name = $element.ProductId 
     # ... work with these variables here;
     #     e.g., output their values (don't use Write-Host, unless
     #     you want to print to the display only).
     $Id, $Name 
  }
}
```

---

Note that, as [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) points out, passing your sample JSON text to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) conveniently parses the JSON array into .NET *objects* (of type `[pscsustomobject]`), whose properties you can access:

However, there is a **caveat in *Windows PowerShell* (no longer in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*)**:

Note: Given that your sample JSON input has extraneous trailing `,` chars. after each object's final property, I'm assuming you're using PowerShell (Core), because Windows PowerShell would complain about that; however, the pitfall discussed below is still worth pointing out for future readers.

If you're *directly* processing the output from a `ConvertFrom-Json` or `Invoke-RestMethod` call that parses a JSON *array* and you want **to process the resulting objects *one by one*, force `ConvertFrom-Json` to *enumerate* the top-level array parsed from JSON by enclosing the call in `(...)`**:

```bash
$json = @'
[
    {
        "Date": "19/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0001",
        "ProductName": "Fizzy Drink",
        "Cost": "2.32",
        "Currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "Date": "16/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0002",
        "ProductName": "Dark Chocolate",
        "Cost": "6.52",
        "Currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "Date": "10/5/2022",
        "ProductId": "0003",
        "ProductName": "Snacks",
        "Cost": "4.2",
        "Currency": "USD"
    }
]
'@

# Note the (...) around the ConvertFrom-Json call, required in Windows PowerShell.
# The same would apply if you send the ConvertFrom-Json output to the *pipeline*:
#    (ConvertFrom-Json $json) | ForEach-Object { "This date: " + $_.Date }
foreach ($obj in (ConvertFrom-Json $json)) {
  "This date: " + $obj.Date
}
```

**Background**:

- In versions before PowerShell (Core) 7.0, `ConvertFrom-Json` and `Invoke-RestMethod` send arrays parsed from JSON as *a whole* through the pipeline, rather than element by element, leading to unexpected behavior.
- Enclosing a command (pipeline) in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) causes these arrays to be enumerated.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578551/45375) for more information.